# How to configure the VSPI of an ESP32 Wroom to communicate with the MAX6675?

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-esp32

I want to use the SPI hardware of the ESP32Wroom.

Here is the code

```
/*
 Name:      spi_dan.ino
 Created:   02/02/2024 20:11:18
 Author:    Daniel
*/
#include <Arduino.h >
#include <SPI.h>
#include "MAX6675.h"

// Définit la broche comme sélection d'esclave : 
const int slaveSelectPin = 5;
float x;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    MAX6675 sonde(slaveSelectPin);
}
void loop() {
    
    x = sonde.readTempC();
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(1000);
}
```

Here is the code for the MAX6675.h that I use

```
// MAX6675.h
#define MAX6675_Settings (SPISettings(1000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1))
#define MAX6675_THERMOCOUPLE_OPEN_BIT 0x04
#define MAX6675_THERMOCOUPLE_OPEN -1.0
#define MAX6675_READ_PERIOD 250
#define MAX6675_CONVERSION_RATIO 0.25

class MAX6675
{
    private:
        uint32_t _lastCallTime;
        int16_t _SSPin;
        uint16_t _incomingMessage;
        float _currentTemp;
            
    public:
        MAX6675 (int16_t SSPin);
        float readTempC();
        float readTempF();
};
```

This is the error message that Visual Micro gives me:

```
Compiling 'spi_dan' for 'ESP32 Dev Module(esp32_esp32)'
Build Folder: "file:///C:/Users/Daniel/AppData/Local/Temp/VMBuilds/spi_dan/esp32_esp32/Release"
 
spi_dan.ino: In function void loop()
 
spi_dan.ino: 20:6: error: 'sonde' was not declared in this scope
   x = sonde.readTempC()
   ^~~~~
spi_dan.ino:20: note  suggested alternative  tone
   x = sonde.readTempC()
   ^~~~~
   tone
Error compiling project sources
Build failed for project 'spi_dan'
```

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you've created the object `sonde` as a local variable in the `setup()` function and can only be used there. `sonde` is not visible outside of this function. When `setup()` finishes and returns, the variable `sonde` is deleted.

```
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
    MAX6675 sonde(slaveSelectPin);
}
```

A quick solution is to declare `sonde` as a global variable. In this case it's visible to all functions inside this file. It also exists for the duration of the program.

```
#include <Arduino.h >
#include <SPI.h>
#include "MAX6675.h"

const int slaveSelectPin = 5;
MAX6675 sonde(slaveSelectPin);
float x;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
}
void loop() {
    x = sonde.readTempC();
    Serial.println(x);
    delay(1000);
}
```